# Insight on how to have two form fields submit to a separate page, 2 pages away

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I'm trying to think of the easiest way for me to get two fields to submit to a page that is 2 pages away.  I know this isn't the best description so let me try to explain.

On page 1 will be the 2 fields, workshop title and instructor, when you click next you will be taken to the second php page that is a poll of 10 questions, when you submit it adds those results to a database and forwards you to the 3rd (different) php page that has 10 more type/text boxes and questions.  The issue here is that the poll has its own polling system, while the text box questions email the results to a specific email address.  I would like the 2 fields from page one to be included into that email, but how can this be done if its not on the same form?

I would like to not have them re-type the 2 fields again, and to make them hidden fields wont work either because the way the polling system works has its own submit button for each question, loses the hidden fields after submit, it just doesn't work.

I tried making the first page submit to a .txt file that holds the info until the 3rd page then it can read it, but then I have the issue with the PHP Mailer not understanding:

```
$f = fopen("data/title.txt", "r");
$titleA = fgets($f);
```

This works by itself out of the mailer.php

```
<?php session_start();
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
$youremail = 'jsadkfjdslkfjs';

$to = $youremail; 
$mailsubject = 'Workshop Feedback Form';
$body = $fromsubject.'

$f = fopen("data/title.txt", "r");
$titleA = fgets($f);


Workshop Title:

'.$titleA.'

Instructor Name:

'.$inameA.'
'; 
mail($to, $mailsubject, $body);
?>
```

I know this is long. I just hope some one can point me in the right direction, I am definitely over looking something.

Comment: Session variables http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass those values through the URL by using `$_GET` and then validate it on the next page.

Another solution would be to use cookies or server sessions.

Comment: I ended up doing the cookie method, and it was surprisingly easier then expected.

Comment: Don't forget to validate any user input

Answer (score 1):

You could pass information between the pages using hidden inputs

- User fills out page 1
- Submits Server gets request, processes/saves if
  necessary
- Server renders page 2, renders `<input type="hidden"
  name="PageOne_SomeFld" value="<?php echo $_POST['SomeFldOnPageOne']; ?>">`
- User fills out page 2
- Submits

etc.
One submission of page 2, server will have the hidden values passed from Page 1

Comment: Yeah, I tried this already as mentioned. The polling system used is a prefab used to my likings and it has 1st question submit, 2nd questions submit, 3rd question submit. I would have to carry that hidden field but they are not 10 different php pages its all on one that pulls the questions etc. I took a stab at it already and couldnt get it to pull over page by page.